# maven dependencies в командной строке

Tags: java, maven, cmd

Ситуация такова: предварительно выложив рабочий мавен проект(из intellijIdea) в гитхаб, я склонировал его в директорию локально. В pom.xml прописана лишь одна dependency,(в моем случае это javazoom). При попытке запуска main класса через командную строку приложение запускается корректно

mvn compile

java -cp ./target/classes мойКласс

Но как только начинается взаимодействие с плеером, то есть с dependency, выскакивает очевидная ошибка

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javazoom.jl.player.Player

так как эта библиотека лишь прописана в pom.xml , но физически отсутствует в директории проекта. Подскажите пожалуйста лаконичное решение в этой ситуации. Другими словами какие команды или взаимодействия необходимы , чтобы можно было запускать мое приложение со всеми вытекающими зависимостями, без использования IDE ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mvn compile
mvn dependency:copy-dependencies
java -cp ./target/classes;./target/dependency/* мойКласс
```

или

```
mvn package
mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="мойКласс"
```

Comment: спасибо! 1 вариант мне кажется очень не практичным для ситуаций, где зависимостей много. 2 крут тем, что дает понимание важности exec-maven-plugin .

Comment: [Чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)